# SuiteScript 2.0 Search Getting Columns Not Results

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am loading a saved search in our NetSuite account using SuiteScript on a Suitelet script.

```
var itemSearchSet = search.load({
    id : 'customsearch253',
});
```

I am then adding a new filter to the search

```
itemSearchSet.filters.push(search.createFilter({
    name : 'itemid',
    operator : search.Operator.ANYOF,
    values : [itemId]
}));
```

I then run the search and return the results

```
return itemSearchSet.run();
```

The results I am getting from this is the columns themselves not the results. I have search heaps of things online and found nothing that matches my issue. Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run()` is not sufficient to retrieve actual results. From there, you'll either need to invoke `each(callback)` to iterate over the results directly or `getRange()` to grab an explicit chunk of the results.

I have a whole bunch of search examples in this YT playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XFuqQrOUIg&list=PLG2tK6Va2WUBP_JCf4nVAbFc6vGuB_lBm